# Check at least one checkbox in the form when the form is expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I have a form that expands when it is checked. When the form is expanded, there are multiple check boxes -  I need to make sure that at least one checkbox is checked at this time. I have the following html/js code that works when none of the checkboxes are selected, but when I select the main checkbox, error goes away. Error should go away when any checkbox is selected in the expanded form.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#checkBtn').click(function() {
      checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;

      if(!checked) {
        alert("You must check at least one checkbox.");
        return false;
      }

    });
  });
```

```css
.inputs {
  display: none;
}

.foo:checked + .inputs {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="foo">
  <input type="checkbox" class="foo"> Pre-designed contour:
  <div class="inputs"> 

    <input type="checkbox" name="contour" value="fiveSeven" id="fiveSeven"> 5x7
    <input type="checkbox"  required id="sixEight"> 6x8
    <input type="checkbox" required id="sixNine"> 6x9
  </div>   
</form>

<input type="button" value="Test Required" id="checkBtn">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking for any checked checkboxes in the code using the line:

```
checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
```

Instead, you should be inspecting the checkboxes in div that is displayed when primary checkbox is selected.

Solution:

Check for the status of primary checkbox on submit button click. If it is selected, then check for number of selected checkboxes in the div that is displayed.

1. Provide an id attribute value (e.g. mainCheckbox ) to main checkbox and same class value (e.g. childCheckbox) to all checkboxes in div that are displayed.
2. On button click event, check for status of main checkbox.

   ```
   if ($('#mainCheckbox')[0].checked) {
       //check for selected checkboxes in div
   }
   ```
3. If it is checked, check for selected checkboxes

   ```
   if ($('#mainCheckbox')[0].checked) {

       if(!$('.childCheckbox:checked').length) {

           alert("You must check at least one checkbox.");

           return false;
       }
   }
   ```

[JSfiddle for solution](https://jsfiddle.net/hv58ofwr/)

Comment: Job Well Done! @Deepansh Sachdeva

Comment: @familyGuy Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery is checking for any `input[type=checkbox]:checked`, which would include the main `#checkBtn` checkbox. Give your form inputs a class and check for those, or change your selector in the jQuery script to look for inputs inside your form only.

Answer (score 1):

You check how many inputs of the type checkbox are checked:

`$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length`

This will always be at least 1, when your main checkbox is checked.

Simply give your other checkboxes a class and only select them or check if length is greater 1.

By the way, you shouldn't put a int into if-clause, take the time and write the expression you really mean.

Answer (score 1):

You gotta add more conditions and optionally ID's for your main checkbox, I tried this HTML Tag instead:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mainbox" class="foo">
```

And the JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var checkedValue;
      $('#checkBtn').click(function() {
          checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;

          if (document.querySelector('#mainbox').checked == true) {
              if (checked == 1) {
                  alert("You must check at least one option.");
                  return false;
              }
          } else if (!checked) {
              alert("You must check at least one checkbox.");
              return false;
          }

      });
  });
```

I made a working JSFiddle example for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/oggdg7dh/

Comment: I don't want the alert when the main box is "not checked" and the button is clicked. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Remove the alert line from my code at the 8th line.

Comment: I'll post another fiddle